# Expand tags inside variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mustache

Is there a way to make Mustache expand the tags inside a variable?

I understand that this is the purpose of partials. However, as you can see in the example below, it is sometimes not practical to use partials due to the structure of the view.

If not, how should I change the structure of the view below? Currently I render the `html` property of each entry in advance. This doesn't seem ideal (and breaks features like changing Mustache's delimiter).

**Example**

The view for a blog's homepage:

```
var view = {
   title: 'Example blog',
   entries: [
     {url: '/a', html: '<p>The first entry on {{title}}</p>'},        
     {url: '/b', html: '<p>The second entry on {{title}}</p>'},     
     {url: '/c', html: '<p>The third entry on {{title}}</p>'}
   ]
};
```

The corresponding template:

```
{{#entries}}
  {{{html}}}
{{/entries}}
```

After calling `Mustache.render`, I receive this.

```
<p>The first entry on {{title}}</p>        
<p>The second entry on {{title}}</p>
<p>The third entry on {{title}}</p>
```

And I would like to receive this:

```
<p>The first entry on Example blog</p>        
<p>The second entry on Example blog</p>
<p>The third entry on Example blog</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mustache doesn't do this, *and you don't want it to*. It's called "mustache injection" and it's equivalent to SQL injection.

When Twitter first started using Mustache client-side, there was an attack where tweeting a URL with Mustache tags in it would cause anyone who viewed that tweet to retweet it. The fix was to prevent Mustache from double-expanding tags.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var view = {
   title: 'Example blog',
   entries: [
     {url: '/a', position: 'first'},        
     {url: '/b', position: 'second'},     
     {url: '/c', position: 'third'}
   ]
};

{{#entries}}
  <p>The {{position}} entry on {{title}} blog</p>
{{/entries}}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I should have been clearer. We can't assume the HTML for each entry is so repetitive – they're blog posts, some of which contain mustache tags.